# how to open pdf in a browser with with disabling the context menu in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have the following code to open up a webpage inside views.py:

```
def pdfView(request,filesPats):
    f = open(filesPats,'rb')
    cont = f.read()
    response = HttpResponse(cont, mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename="'+my_file+'.pdf"'
    f.close()
    return response
```

I use django 1.4 and python 2.7.
 It returns a PDF view and it works fine. But the question is : how to disable the context menu inside the pdf viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at **[this plugin](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)**.

All you need to do is customize it according to your need.